# error while using selenium and writing to file

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, beautifulsoup

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
import re
import pandas as pd
from pytube import YouTube


browser = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe")



browser.get("https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCaKt8dvEIPnEHWSbLYhzrxg/videos")
time.sleep(1)

elem = browser.find_element_by_tag_name("body")

no_of_pagedowns = 100

while no_of_pagedowns:
    elem.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
    time.sleep(0.2)
    no_of_pagedowns-=1

html = browser.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
tags = soup.find_all('a')
fname = "C:/Stock_in_CFD/Output.txt"
text_file = open(fname, "w+", encoding="utf-8")
for tag in tags:
    t = tag.get('href')
    text_file.write(t)
```

When I am running the above code. I am getting error

TypeError: write() argument must be str, not None

When I am not using selenium I am able to do it.
I am using selenium since I want scroll down entire page before parsing before using BeautifulSoup

Comment: Try printing `tags` to debug what it has first... it probably has a result without an `href`.